# Don't understand how this numpy operation works for two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I see by exercising the below code is working but don't figure out why?
This is using python numpy.

The first code snippet shows I have one dimension numpy array c, a two dimension numpy array b, with c's values are within the range of the row number of b, then b[c] is working and we get an expanded array.

```
import numpy as np
c=np.array([2,3,4,5,1,4,3,4,3,1,4,3,4,1,4,5])
print("c is\n",c)
print("=========================")
b=np.random.rand(6,3)
print("b is\n ",b)
print("=========================")
print("b[c] is\n",b[c])

c is
 [2 3 4 5 1 4 3 4 3 1 4 3 4 1 4 5]
=========================
b is
  [[0.85983145 0.25222867 0.02340111]
 [0.82655905 0.80128734 0.83493173]
 [0.01817893 0.64987559 0.4190797 ]
 [0.10836948 0.40150688 0.59126363]
 [0.59367641 0.38069116 0.82918134]
 [0.02770242 0.62288968 0.46228432]]
=========================
b[c] is
 [[0.01817893 0.64987559 0.4190797 ]
 [0.10836948 0.40150688 0.59126363]
 [0.59367641 0.38069116 0.82918134]
 [0.02770242 0.62288968 0.46228432]
 [0.82655905 0.80128734 0.83493173]
 [0.59367641 0.38069116 0.82918134]
 [0.10836948 0.40150688 0.59126363]
 [0.59367641 0.38069116 0.82918134]
 [0.10836948 0.40150688 0.59126363]
 [0.82655905 0.80128734 0.83493173]
 [0.59367641 0.38069116 0.82918134]
 [0.10836948 0.40150688 0.59126363]
 [0.59367641 0.38069116 0.82918134]
 [0.82655905 0.80128734 0.83493173]
 [0.59367641 0.38069116 0.82918134]
 [0.02770242 0.62288968 0.46228432]]
```

However, if I change the same to list as below, it will not work:

```
>>> a=[[3,4,3],[4,5,3],[3,4,2]]
>>> b=[2,3,2,1]
>>> a[b]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

What is the difference? What's the operation called in numpy? I can't find out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
b=np.random.rand(6,3)
c=np.array([2,3,4,5,1,4,3,4,3,1,4,3,4,1,4,5])
b[c]
```

you use Numpy's [integer array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) to pluck values at given offsets.

That's simply not a thing with regular Python lists. If you wanted to emulate something similar, you'd do

```
a = [[3,4,3],[4,5,3],[3,4,2]]
b = [2,3,2,1]
c = [a[i] for i in b]
```

Comment: Thanks AKX, it is working :>>> a
[[3, 4, 3], [4, 5, 3], [3, 4, 2]]
>>> b
[2, 1, 2, 1]
>>> c=[a[i] for i in b]
>>> c
[[3, 4, 2], [4, 5, 3], [3, 4, 2], [4, 5, 3]]